# SQL error 'core_resource' already exists

Tags: magento

I am getting following message when I run mageno  on my local host

```
Error in file: "D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'core_resource' already exists

Trace:
#0 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.2')
#2 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.2')
#3 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 D:\wamp\www\magentocustmod\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This occurs while setup another Magento into the same database (e.g., for testing new version of the script using different tables prefix)

Comment: If not then - Delete /var/cache
- Check permissions in .htaccess in root folder and /var (Put them 644)
- Make /var and /media 777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had "core_resource" table blank.I restored the database and everything worked fine.

I was trying to upgrade a Magento installation  to a higher version on the same My SQL server.

So there was the existing database already there and I was trying to import the database in to newly created database.

I think this was the main problem for this error to me.

Answer (score 3):

**There are many problems that can cause this error**

I know that this question has already been answered, but I just ran into the same problem. The selected solution here by the OP did not solve my problem. So I created this blog post to analyze the many different causes and find the solution that worked for me. Hopefully it will be of benefit to the next person that runs into this error.

**Possible Causes**

- Rolling back the database after installing an extension
- Rolling back the database after upgrading Magento
- During installation of a fresh Magento

**Possible solutions for your situation**

- Solution 1: Restore Magento to the last working state
- Solution 2: Update the upgrade flag for this extension as mentioned by abhijeet
- Solution 3: Delete the database tables in question

This article was the source of my research, [Base table or view already exists](http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/solution-to-base-table-or-view-already-exists/)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience I hit this bug installing a empty 1.9.0 install. The bug is really when you don't fill the table prefix. So putting "mg_" as table prefix allows me to perform the install

Comment: Didn't help in my case either (clean 1.9.3.1 install with mg_ table prefix)
But when i got the message i just dropped the mentioned table and after reloading the page it finished the install.
Clearly a bug in the installer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what operation you are performing right now but you can resolve this issue by deleting core_resource table or by executing this query

```
INSERT INTO  `core_resource` (

`code` ,
`version` ,
`data_version`
)
VALUES (
'core_setup',  '1.6.0.0',  '1.6.0.0'
)
```

Magento will automatically create this table again. For safety you can keep the table backup also. Magento is not getting any entry of this setup resource in core_resource table and that's way its executing this **app\code\core\Mage\Core\sql\core_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php** setup file again.